# Accessing BigQuery with Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I look on the internet to see how can I import bigquery data inside google spreadsheet.
I found this appscript sample, but it doesn'twork API are not at the same level, and I do not find how to query with API2 or API@beta1 in appscript.

```
function runQuery() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var range = ss.getRangeByName('query');
  var query = range.getCell(1, 1).getValue();
  //var results = bigquery.query(query);



  var header = ss.getRangeByName('header');
  header.clearContent();
  var output = ss.getRangeByName('output');
  output.clearContent();
  for (var i = 0; i < results.fields.length; i++) {
    var field = results.fields[i];
    header.getCell(1, 1 + i).setValue(field.id);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
    var row = results.rows[i].f;
    for (var j = 0; j < row.length; ++j) {
      output.getCell(1 + i, 1 + j).setValue(row[j].v);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your ideas,

GQ

Comment: These instructions worked for me: https://greenido.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/big-query-and-google-spreadsheet-intergration/

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE: We just added a new BigQuery + Apps Script Tutorial that should walk you through the answer to this question here:** https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/bigquery_tutorial

@GQuery: We've very recently updated AppsScript to have access to the latest BigQuery API version (v2). Here's a simple example to get started, will display results in the AppScript log. We are working on an update to the AppScript/BigQuery documentation.

```
function runQuery() {
  var projectId = 'YOUR PROJECT';
  var sql = 'select word, word_count from publicdata:samples.shakespeare limit 100';
  var queryResults;

  // Run the query
  try {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(projectId, sql);
  }
  catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    return;
  }

  // Loop until successful job completion
  while (queryResults.getJobComplete() == false) {
    try {
      queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, queryResults.getJobReference().getJobId());
    }
    catch (err) {
      Logger.log(err);
      return;
    }
  }

  var tableRows = queryResults.getRows();
  for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    var rowString = '';
    var cols = tableRows[i].getF();
    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
      rowString += cols[j].getV() + '\t';
    }
    Logger.log(rowString);
```

Comment: Dear Michael,I tried your solution. May I asked an extra question.
In order to access to those public data, I have to specify a projectid.
as I am in google spreadhseet, is it the appscript project key ?

because I get an exception and the following messages  :
Exception: Invalid Project ID "..." Project IDs must contain alphanumeric characters and be at most 63 characters long,

Comment: Good Question: projectId should reference your Google Dev Console Project ID, which you need to set up here: https://code.google.com/apis/console. While you can get your available projectId(s) via BigQuery API, a quick way to view your projectId is to take a look at the URL in the project you create: https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1#project:265312182736

Comment: Hi Michael, do you have a sample spreadsheet to share. I tried but I am not able to access to my sample or google sample data ?!

Comment: Can you let me know what the error is? Don't forget to enable BigQuery V2 under "Resources->Google APIs Services"

Comment: Hi Michael, it works. Rereading your post, I understood my error : I was using API key instead of ProjectID that is in the URL of my console. Thank you for help and the time spent. GQ

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the reputation to comment on hurricaneditka16. Therefore, I posted this answer:
This line

```
queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(projectId, sql);
```

Should be replaced by

```
.query(
    resource,
    projectId);
```

Resource is a slight transformation on the sql you used before. Try this transformation and it will work.

```
function getResource(sql) {
  var resource = '{"query": "sql"}'
  resource = resource.replace('sql', sql);
  return resource
}
```