# Using BigQuery in Google Apps Scripts to connect to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-bigquery

I've enabled BigQuery in API console and in my GAS app and I tried using the example from this thread: [Accessing BigQuery with Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775975/accessing-bigquery-with-google-spreadsheet/10777975#10777975)

I got the Project ID but I don't know how to connect to my Google Spreadsheet.

How do you use BigQuery in GAS to connect to Google Spreadsheet anyway?  Do you input the Spreadsheet as a dataset in the API console? How is that done?

The V2 documentation has several tutorials and samples but none about connecting to a Google Spreadsheet using GAS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can call Google BigQuery from Spreadsheet using GAS. But you can't read values in Google Spreadsheet from Google BigQuery Queries.

Google BigQuery is separate product where you have to upload the data into Google BigQuery to query. Google BigQuery wont read the Spreadsheet automatically. You got to export the Spreasheet as CSV first and upload into BigQuery before you can query the data.

What you can do is you can use the Spreadsheet as a Front end to BigQuery , for example users can populate some fields in the spreadsheet and GAS can use that values and query the BigQuery to get results and populate the spreadsheet and use visualization gadgets like charts in spreadsheet to view the data.

Comment: So, it doesn't do direct query/connect to a spreadsheet using GAS?

Comment: sabansm, can you explain your use case? I'd like to know more about it.

Comment: 2013 update: It's possible to stream data from Spreadsheets to BigQuery now.