# BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm trying to replace the contents of a Google Sheet with a BigQuery query.

I'm in the Google Sheet and using a script based on these: https://greenido.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/big-query-and-google-spreadsheet-intergration/
[Accessing BigQuery with Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775975/accessing-bigquery-with-google-spreadsheet/10777975#10777975)

All the script does is pull the info from a BigQuery query and write it to a Google Sheet. But if I just run the script, I end up getting an error: *BigQuery: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found*

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: also it helps in many cases to search for already asked similar questions! I do remember seeing quite a number of related (I think)

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I did find similar questions before I posted but none of them (as far as I could tell) dealt with my specific issue.

Answer (score 12):

After a lot of Googling, I found the answer. Apparently, even though I need to give my script the authority to manage *not just* my Google Sheet, but also the authority to manage my Google Drive.

All I have to do is add a function to make Google ask me for permission for the script to manage my Drive.

Here's the function:

```
function usingAppsScriptsToken ()}
  // we need to provoke a drive dialog
  // DriveApp.getFiles()
}
```

Note that key ingredient is DriveApp.getFiles(), and it still works even though it's commented. When I run the function, I'll get a pop-up window that says "(your script) would like to View and manage the files in your Google Drive". When I allow it, the data import function works.

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aP6pxK3jexc)

Comment: that's a great catch! the scopes should've been based on what you enable in the advanced services, but it's not. Hopefully Google will fix that eventually. The same  happens when you try to access a Google Sheets based table in Bigquery via the API / App Scripts

Answer (score 2):

No need to add anything to your code.

You simply need to add an additional scope to the dependencies part of the appscript.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
  "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
    "userSymbol": "BigQuery",
    "serviceId": "bigquery",
    "version": "v2"
  },
  { 
    "userSymbol": "Drive",
    "serviceId": "drive",
    "version": "v2"
  }]
}
```

In the View menu you could select to Show the manifest file:

[image]

Comment: You don't show any modified scopes here. An enabled advanced service only provides autocomplete functionality in the Apps Script editor.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
DriveApp.getFiles()
```

to any function in your project and run it. After your running, you see a window that asks permission to the Drive.

[image: 1-st step]

[image: 2-step]

[image: 3-rd step]

Afterall you can delete this row and everything is will be ok.