# BigQuery - Google Sheets error when try to refresh data connection using macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

Trying to refresh BigQuery data connection (Google Sheets) using Macro, but it failed. It showed this error:

[BigQuery error: Error while reading table: worker-information.worker_details.xxxx_global_worker_malaysia, error message: Failed to read the spreadsheet. Errors: No OAuth token with Google Drive scope was found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpY6x.png)

Here is the macro script:

```
 function refresh2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceTables()[0].refreshData();
};
```

and this

```
function refresh() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Master Worker Details Database'), true);
  SpreadsheetApp.enableAllDataSourcesExecution();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getDataSourceTables()[0].refreshData();
};
```

The problem only happens when I try to refresh the data connection using Macro. If I refresh it manually, it's okay.

I already try to follow the step explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49807276/bigquery-no-oauth-token-with-google-drive-scope-was-found) but the error still exist. Here is the script that I modified based on the explanation.

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "BigQuery",
      "serviceId": "bigquery",
      "version": "v2"
  },
  { 
    "userSymbol": "Drive",
    "serviceId": "drive",
    "version": "v2"
  }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "sheets": {
    "macros": [{
      "menuName": "refresh_master_worker_database",
      "functionName": "refresh_master_worker_database"
    }]
  }
}
```

**[UPDATE - 27 NOVEMBER 2019]**

I already fix the error using this method <[LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aP6pxK3jexc)>.

Comment: Could you try this first? If it works, please mark your question as duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49807276/bigquery-no-oauth-token-with-google-drive-scope-was-found

Comment: @YunZhang I have try before, it doesn't work, or I'm doing it wrong?